# How do you use Jsoup to search for a string on a website?

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I am trying to use Jsoup to search a website to see if it contains a string. Is this even possible, and if so, how is it done?

Comment: What have you tried?  Did you review the documentation here?  https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible and actually quite easy if you are using Jsoup. To simply see if a specific Web-Page **contains** a specific string then you might do something like the following example:

Let say we want to see if the following string exists within the **Jsoup** home web-page (https://jsoup.org/):

```
If you have any questions on how to use jsoup
```

Your code could look something like this:

```
String stringToFind = "If you have any questions on how to use jsoup";
try {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://jsoup.org/").get();
    if (doc.text().contains(stringToFind)) {
        System.out.println("Yes...String exists in web-page.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("No...String does not exist in web-page.");
    }
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    // Do whatever you like to handle the exception...
}
```